# How to find ERC721 compliant NFTs owned by an address?

Tags: javascript, nft

Is there any way to get the current owner's address of an nft? I need to use it in my project in unity. I'm new to these things, I would be glad if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't implemented automatically so it is only if the specific contract that created the nft implements it. You need the contract address that created the nft, then you can inspect the code to see if it has something like a tokenIdToOwner mapping.